# Macbook Pro - Bootcamp - Partition problems

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, macbook-pro, boot-camp, osx-el-capitan

I have a MacBookPro with Bootcamp. As I mainly use the Bootcamp Windows, I wanted to decrease the Mac partition and increase the bootcamp partition.

A few articles online said to make the mac partition smaller in mac os, and then go back into windows to resize the Bootcamp partition.

The problem was that El Capitan doesn't seem to let you delete a partition and leave the space free. El Capitan seems to display a pie diagram, which always enforces the free space to be filled with a new partition. No partition type I choose was viewable by Windows - it only displayed one big partition other than my bootcamp partition ...

[image]

The first 98GB partition should actually now be two partitions - The Mac OS 39GB partition and a 59GB one which I want to delete so I can expand my bootcamp partition.

To make things worse, I think I've messed up by trying to delete that space in Mac OS with gdisk. I tried to delete that 39GB partition with the 'd' command, but now MacOS's disk utility doesn't see this space at all - so the total partition size no longer adds up to the total 251GB disk size!

[image]

Note that the total size in those two partitions doesn't add up to 251GB anymore.

Viewing it in Windows disk management still looks the same as the screenshot above - ie. it just sees this big "GPT Protected Partition" which is the size of both the El Capitan partition and also the one I "deleted" which El Capitan can no longer see.

Incase it helps - going back to EL Capitan, here's what running the 'p' command in gdisk displays ...

[image]

It feels like time to ask for help before I screw things up even more :( How can I get this 59GB back so I can resize my Bootcamp partition to include it?

**UPDATE**:

Trying EaseUS Partition Master in Windows lets me see the unallocated space ...

[image]

However, if I try to resize the Bootcamp partition, I get the following error ...

[image]

A google search shows a forum post where EaseUS says their software doesn't fully support Mac and Bootcamp and they don't recommend doing it ...

http://forum.easeus.com/viewtopic.php?t=31595

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone has a better answer, but I have also run into this problem before. After several frustrating days troubleshooting, I backed up everything I needed on my Windows and Mac machines, and then reinstalled OS X from the Web using recovery mode. From there, I set my hard drive to desired partitions and installed Windows. It was the least painful of all the solutions, even if was heavy handed.

You may consider using VMWare or Parallels, which are more flexible than using BootCamp, if you plan on resizing your partitions as needed or need to recover your Windows more machine easily.

Comment: Might have to do this :( I have a lot of stuff installed, so wanted to avoid doing this. It could do with a fresh install though anyway. What a PITA :(